# findOne send NULL in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I want to render a product in my database, using findOne. I get the id passed in my url to look for the product by its id.

However, I got `null` as a result.

Here is my `server.js` file.

```
app.get('/boutique/:id', (request, reponse) => {
    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var dbo = db.db("pool");
        var cherche_id = request.params.id;

        dbo.collection("products").findOne({id : cherche_id}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            reponse.render('boutique_id');

            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

It also works if I change my findOne like that :

```
findOne({id : 2},
```

Answer (score 2):

`request.params.id` is a string while the `id` field in your database is a number. MongoDB compares types first so `"2"` is not equal to `2`. You need to cast the value to number first:

```
var cherche_id = +request.params.id;
```

EDIT: the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) converts string to a number in this case